# Using Look-ahead and Look-behind (perl)

Tags: regex, perl

I want to split with perl code this type of line:

```
my $my_town = Madrid(32): Villa de Madrid (ES) Royal Palace of Madrid (Teatro Real)
```

to:

```
Madrid(32):
Villa de Madrid (ES)
Royal Palace of Madrid (Teatro Real)
```

I tried:

```
my @travel = split(/(?<=\))\s*/, $my_town);
```

but output result is:

```
Madrid(32)
: Villa de Madrid (ES)
Royal Palace of Madrid (Teatro Real)
```

Please give me a little help.

Is there any way that function look-behind for ")" to return all finds fewer first character? ": Villa de Madrid (ES)" without first string ":", "Royal Palace of Madrid (Teatro Real)" without first string "white space", ...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`split` could do the job

```
my @matches = split(
   qr/
      (?: (?<= \) : ) 
      |   (?<= \) (?! : ) )
      )
      \s*
   /x,
   $my_town,
);
```

But since the input doesn't really look like a uniformly separated list to me, I think it's the wrong tool for the job. Notice how moving towards a parser is simpler:

```
my @matches = $my_town =~ / \S .*? \( [^)]+ \) :? /xgs;
```

Comment: Does not work as required, `Madrid(32): Villa de Madrid (ES)` is the first match. `/ \S .*? \( [^)]+ \) :? /xg` works better.

Comment: @Qtax, Thanks, fixed (although I didn't use your fix)

Comment: OP wanted to have `:` included at the end of the first match tho.

Comment: @user934718, As Qtax pointed out, I misread the question. Fixed. (I think I saw the output of sln's post)

Comment: @Qtax, I think I confused sln's post as part of the OP's, and sln doesn't output a ":". Fixed.

Answer (score 2):

Not a very scientific way to split up a line.

```
use strict;
use warnings;

my $my_town = 'Madrid(32): Villa de Madrid (ES) Royal Palace of Madrid (Teatro Real)  ';
my @travel = split( / (?<=\)):? \s* /x  , $my_town );

for (@travel) {
   print "'$_'\n";
}
```

'Madrid(32)'
'Villa de Madrid (ES)'
'Royal Palace of Madrid (Teatro Real)'

** edit **

I don't know why but if you're just wrestling with that variable length lookbehind issue
and want to see how you could include an optional colon `:` as part of the split
you could always do this:

```
my @travel = split( / (?:(?<=\):)|(?<=\))(?!:)) \s* /x  , $my_town );
```

'Madrid(32):'
'Villa de Madrid (ES)'
'Royal Palace of Madrid (Teatro Real)'

Comment: First code work good without colon : as part of split. Thanks. Second code not work at all.

Comment: @user934718: Both the first and second code work perfectly for the respective output they produce. But I'm mostly guessing on whats needed.